# What is the correct pronunciation? 'Mesirut nefesh' or 'mesirat nefesh'?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk

Which is correct? Mesir**u**t nefesh or mesir**a**t nefesh?
I have always used mesirut, but see mesirat also.

Comment: Mesira**s** Nefesh :P While I'm sort of joking a little, I am trying to bring out the idea that there probably isn't a single _correct_ pronunciation, as there are probably dozens of different Mesorahs on pronunciation (and they can all be 'correct'). And as an aside, this is probably also off-topic due to being about the Hebrew language, not Judaism.

Answer (score 1):

Mesir**u**t in Hebrew means "devotion", while mesir**a**t is the gerund of the verb *limsor*, which means "to deliver".

Source: *[Limsor](https://milog.co.il/%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8)*

> ***העביר*** לידי אדם אחר; נתן (to hand over)

*[Mesirut](https://milog.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA)*

> ***נאמנות*** ומחויבות לדבר מה

*Neemanut* means devotion in Hebrew.

Comment: Thanks. No one, or almost no one, here knows you personally to take your word for it, so can you [edit] in some support for your claims?